# Is there a general purpose parser for Java bytecode?

Tags: java, parsing, jvm, bytecode

I'm trying perform a classification algorithm on a feature set derived from JAR files. I want to disassemble the JAR file create text corpus from where I can extract features to pass to the classifier.

The problem is, Java bytecode (I'm using javap -c -v) has a lot of things I don't care for that could result in useless features.

Is there an available parser I can use for Java bytecode that gets rid of syntactic characters?

Comment: Let me get that straight: you want to do per hand optimization of Java byte code?

Comment: Not an optimization, just analysis of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/). It is fast, light-weight and well documented.

It comes with a generator which allows generating the code which would be necessary to construct the bytecode with ASM for a certain class file.